# How To Get The Object Type Of The Anonymous Type Passed To The Function Without Creating An Instance Of That Object

Tags: .net, vb.net, object, types, anonymous-types

I know I can get a type of the passed object type this way

```
Public Function ConvertToValidationDataModel(Of T)(ByVal oSourceObject As Object) As Object
        Dim oDestinationObject As Object
        Dim oDestinationObjectType As Type

        oDestinationObject = Activator.CreateInstance(Of T)()

        oDestinationObjectType = oDestinationObject.GetType() 

End Function
```

but is there a way to get a type whithout the hoops of creating an instance of the object?

Otherwords  - is there something like this?

```
Dim oType AS Type = GetType(Of T)
```

Comment: Can't you call GetType(T)?

Comment: When I do `Dim oType  As Type = GetType(OF T)` it underlines Of and saying `Keyword does not name a type'

Comment: Read my comment again, it says GetType(T) not GetType(Of T)

Answer (score 1):

You have the type already, it's the generic parameter T. The following is a small console app along with its output:

http://grab.by/yO2S

```
Module Module1
Sub Main()
    Foo(Of Integer)(1)
    Foo(Of String)(1)

    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine(Foo(Of Boolean)(True))

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Public Function Foo(Of T)(ByVal oSourceObject As Object) As Type
    If TypeOf oSourceObject Is T Then
        Console.WriteLine("Types match.")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Types mismatch.")
    End If

    Return GetType(T)
End Function
End Module
```